# How to replace a string in a text file which starts with a specific word and ends with a special character in C#?

Tags: c#, regex, append, text-files

I am developing an app which offers management of a production process by reading and writing to a text file. First of all, it reads from the text file and puts the information into a datagridview like:

[image]

And then it should be possible to update the information in the text file when a cell value is changed.

Here is the example test file:

> 567,Eindhoven,IGT,21,Stripping_e=20/05/2020,Stripping_s=21/05/2020,Stripping_f=,Cleaning_e=23/05/2020,Cleaning_s=27/05/2020,Cleaning_f=28/05/2020,Paint_e=28/05/2020,Paint_s=28/05/2020,Paint_f=29/05/2020,Cabinet_e=29/05/2020,Cabinet_s=31/05/2020,Cabinet_f=,Table_e=,Table_s=,Table_f=05/06/2020,Stand_e=05/06/2020,Stand_s=08/06/2020,Stand_f=,Display_e=08/06/2020,Display_s=11/06/2020,Display_f=,UControls_e=15/06/2020,UControls_s=,UControls_f=,Test_e=19/06/2020,Test_s=,Test_f=20/06/2020,Prepack_e=21/06/2020,Prepack_s=22/06/2020,Prepack_f=,Endpack_e=27/06/2020,Endpack_s=28/06/2020,Endpack_f=,Release_e=30/06/2020,Release_s=,Release_f=,

What I want to do is basically replace the date stored in the file with the new one entered in the cell. For example for `Cleaning_e=23/05/2020,` I want to check if the string starts with `Cleaning_e=` and ends with `,`  replace it with `Cleaning_e=12/09/2020,` i.e. entered new date in the cell.

My current code is:

```
private void ExportToTextFile(int selectedDate)
        {
            string filename = dataGridView1.Rows[clickedRow].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
           // TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter($"../../{filename}.txt");
            var text = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (string s in File.ReadAllLines($"../../{filename}.txt"))
            {
               /* if (clickedColumn == 3 && selectedDate == 0)
                    text.AppendLine(s.Replace("Stripping_e=", $"Stripping_e={dataGridView1.Rows[clickedRow].Cells[clickedColumn].Value.ToString()}"));
                else if (clickedColumn == 3 && selectedDate == 1)
                    text.AppendLine(s.Replace("Stripping_s=", $"Stripping_s={dataGridView1.Rows[clickedRow].Cells[clickedColumn].Value.ToString()}"));
                else if (clickedColumn == 3 && selectedDate == 2)
                    text.AppendLine(s.Replace("Stripping_f=", $"Stripping_f={dataGridView1.Rows[clickedRow].Cells[clickedColumn].Value.ToString()}"));
                else if (clickedColumn == 3 && selectedDate == 3)
                    text.AppendLine(s.Replace("Stripping_d=", $"Stripping_d={dataGridView1.Rows[clickedRow].Cells[clickedColumn].Value.ToString()}"));
                else */if (clickedColumn == 4 && selectedDate == 0)
                {
                    text.AppendLine(s.Replace("Cleaning_e=", $"Cleaning_e={dataGridView1.Rows[clickedRow].Cells[clickedColumn].Value.ToString()}"));
                    
                }/*
                else if (clickedColumn == 4 && selectedDate == 1)
                    text.AppendLine(s.Replace("Cleaning_s=", $"Cleaning_s={dataGridView1.Rows[clickedRow].Cells[clickedColumn].Value.ToString()}"));
                else if (clickedColumn == 4 && selectedDate == 2)
                    text.AppendLine(s.Replace("Cleaning_f=", $"Cleaning_f={dataGridView1.Rows[clickedRow].Cells[clickedColumn].Value.ToString()}"));
                else if (clickedColumn == 4 && selectedDate == 3)
                    text.AppendLine(s.Replace("Cleaning_d=", $"Cleaning_d={dataGridView1.Rows[clickedRow].Cells[clickedColumn].Value.ToString()}"));*/
            }
            using (var file = new StreamWriter(File.Create($"../../{filename}.txt")))
            {
                file.Write(text.ToString());
            }

        }
```

After I did `text.AppendLine(s.Replace("Cleaning_e=",$"Cleaning_e={dataGridView1.Rows[clickedRow].Cells[clickedColumn].Value.ToString()}"));` it wrote into the file: `Cleaning_e=12/09/202023/05/2020`.

How do I make sure to get rid of the old date entered before I append the new date?

I tried removing this string and writing into the index of the removed string, but I could not make it work. I also tried using regex but I was not successful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to replace it with Regex you can use

```
var testText = "some other stuff Cleaning_e=12/43/4555, some more ";
var newValue = "78/65/0000";
var rx = new Regex(@"Cleaning_e=(\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d)?");
var result = rx.Replace(testText, $"Cleaning_e={newValue}");
```

this will replace the date. Beware that this replaces every occurance of Cleaning_e and requires the date format to be exactly to have axactly 2 2 and 4 Digits. If the number of digits vary, you can use

```
var rx = new Regex(@"Cleaning_e=(\d+/\d+/\d+)?");
```

instead.

I'd rather recomment to parse this into a proper structure and change the values there rather than Manipulating the text file directly.

Answer (score 2):

If it were me... I'd first parse the file by breaking all of the fields at the command (using `string.Split`):

```
private const string SomeStuff =
    "567,Eindhoven,IGT,21,Stripping_e=20/05/2020,Stripping_s=21/05/2020,Stripping_f=,Cleaning_e=23/05/2020,Cleaning_s=27/05/2020,Cleaning_f=28/05/2020,Paint_e=28/05/2020,Paint_s=28/05/2020,Paint_f=29/05/2020,Cabinet_e=29/05/2020,Cabinet_s=31/05/2020,Cabinet_f=,Table_e=,Table_s=,Table_f=05/06/2020,Stand_e=05/06/2020,Stand_s=08/06/2020,Stand_f=,Display_e=08/06/2020,Display_s=11/06/2020,Display_f=,UControls_e=15/06/2020,UControls_s=,UControls_f=,Test_e=19/06/2020,Test_s=,Test_f=20/06/2020,Prepack_e=21/06/2020,Prepack_s=22/06/2020,Prepack_f=,Endpack_e=27/06/2020,Endpack_s=28/06/2020,Endpack_f=,Release_e=30/06/2020,Release_s=,Release_f=,";
var fields = SomeStuff.Split(new[]{','}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

At that point, you'd have a collection of strings.  Then I'd create a regex like the following:

```
private const string ParsePattern = @"(?<key>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)=(?<date>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})";
private static readonly Regex ParseRegex = new Regex(ParsePattern);
```

That regex looks for any number of letters, numbers or underscores, followed by "=" followed by two digits, a slash, another two digits, another slash and finally four more digits.  The "group" before the equals sign will be named "key" and the date after the equals sign named "date".

Finally, I'd build a list of fields that don't have a date and a dictionary to hold field-name/date combinations:

```
var noDateStrings = new List<string>();
var dateDictionary = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
```

With that in had, I'd loop through my parsed collection of strings.  If there's a match to the regex, I'd take the two components and put them in the dictionary.  If there's no match, then I'd stick them into my no-match `List<string>`:

```
foreach (var field in fields)
{
    var patternMatches = ParseRegex.Matches(field);
    if (patternMatches.Count == 0)
    {
        noDateStrings.Add(field);
    }
    else
    {
        var groups = patternMatches[0].Groups;
        var date = DateTime.ParseExact(groups["date"].ToString(), "dd/mm/yyyy",
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        dateDictionary.Add(groups["key"].ToString(), date);
    }
}
```

You have all the information you need here to do whatever you'd like.

One final thing to note.  I almost always advocate for using `TryParse` instead of `Parse` when parsing things.  However, in this case, I know that the string matches a date pattern.  Unless that string represents an illegal date (say 32/13/2020), then it will parse fine.

Comment: This answer is more polished than mine. Refer to this preferably.

Comment: I didn't say how to write it all back.  With this solution, it might make sense to add everything to the dictionary (and make it a `Dictionary<string, DateTime?> (or use a `List<KeyValuePair<string, DateTime?>>), adding null entries for the non-matches.  Then writing it out simply becomes a walk through the dictionary

Comment: @GrimmReaper I used your solution since you posted first but I realized that sometimes I do not have a date stored in the text file such as `Cleaning_e=,` In this case I only want to put the new date without deleting anything. How could I handle this case?

Comment: Change the dictionary to `Dictionary<string, DateTime?>`. Then set the value to `null` when there is no date

Comment: For the regex bit to be optional you can use ?. I'll edit my answer in case you want to keep using the quick and dirty solution

Comment: Do you only care about the `Cleaning_e=` case?  What about the cases like `567,Eindhoven,IGT,21,`?  If it's just the empty date, change the pattern to `@"(?<key>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)=(?<date>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})?"` and take care of an empty `date` by adding `null` to the dictionary where there is no date.